# How to Grab the December 1st of This Current Year

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Example:

I want to grab the 1st of December of the current year using thecurrent date.

If the year changes, for example the current_date is now 2024-01-01 I want the 1st of December of the current year for that date instead.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [truncation functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#truncation-function) and add 11 months. For example:

```
select date_trunc('year', current_date) + interval '11' month;
```

Output:

```
   _col0    
------------
 2023-12-01
```